# Rhino Mock using an expect on 'new' method call

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to do some form of expect NEW in rhino mock.

Example:

```
public void ToBeTested()
{
     ClassForExmaple classForExample = new ClassForExample();

     //Other logic.....
}
```

So I want my unit test to call ToBeTested(), but when the new ClassForExample is called I want it to return a mocked version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not worked with Rhino mock and I am not sure if this is something that is supported by RhinoMock but the fact that the control of creation of the object is embedded within the method violates the principles of DI/IOC and thus is harder to test.. Ideally the class should have been injected to the method either through the constructor of the containing class or to the method itself..

thus

```
class A
{
    IClassForExample _classForExample;
    public A(IClassForExample classForExample)
    {
      _classForExample=classForExample;
    }
    public void ToBeTested()
    {
         var classForExample = _classForExample;

         //Other logic.....
    }
}
```

Does RhinoSupport extending a non-abstract/interface class - a question I am not sure but I am sure it can mock the interface.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, for the same reason you cannot expect `static` things : it is not called on an instance.

If you want to use a mock for an object that is built within your tested code, you should have something like this :

```
internal virtual ClassForExample NewClassForExempe()
{
    return new ClassForExample();
}
```

and then mock this method in your test.

Note : I put the method internal assuming you have rhino mocks declared in [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) of your class. Otherwise you'll have to make it public.

Comment: polluting a production class just to enable testing is probably not the way to go..

Comment: Well, it's not about polluting, but writing "test friendly" code. I guess some people would see adding a parameter as pollution too.

Comment: Didn't you just say a factory method was pollution ? Because someone wrote it in a book doesn't mean it's definitively a good solution for everyone.

Comment: Would you write such an implementation of a class and provide it as an API for others to consume? Think logically dont argue for the heck of it.. Whats it got to do with someone writing in a book apart from just one more person vouching for it..